# Opamps in double inverter configuration setup giving -1 to 5V instead of 0-5V

Tags: power-supply

I am making a variable power supply that can vary voltages from 0 to 5V.

I had first though of using the LM317 but then figured out that the minimum voltage it can output is 1.25V which isnt acceptable for me.

I then tried a unity gain opamp (the LM741) configuration with a potentiometer at the non-inverting input of the opamp. It seemed to work but then I realized that it varied voltages in the range 2-5V. I learnt that opamps in the unity gain, or buffer, configuration output a minimum of 2V no matter what the input is.

Finally, I switched to a double inverter opamp configuration, the schematic of which I have attached here. The 1k resistors have been replaced with 10k resistors. The problem is that the max output is indeed 5V but the minimum output is -1V. How do I fix this?[image: My schematic]

Comment: "I learnt that opamps in the unity gain, or buffer, configuration output a minimum of 2V no matter what the input is."  Nope.  There are quite a few op-amps that cannot drive the output to within 2V of their negative power rail, but there are quite a few that can.  Maybe change your source of information, or read your sources more carefully?

Comment: I tried the buffer configuration. Unfortunately, my  voltage never went below the 2V mark.

Comment: Perhaps you should ask a separate question, showing the schematic you used and giving part numbers.  That shouldn't be -- and just because it happened to you, once, doesn't mean that it happens to everyone, all the time.

Comment: Speaking of which -- *edit this question* to say what op-amps you're using.

Comment: ... and also inform the current (mA) requirement at the 0-5V output.

Comment: Really sorry but I'm a newbie to all this. I'm a freshman in college and have a lot of stuff to learn. I'll let you guys in on the requirements. There is no minimum or max current requirement. The only requirement is voltage regualtion.

Comment: Short circuit current is 25mA for the 741.  Is that enough for you to use it as a variable power supply??

Answer (score 3):

This is your circuit when the potentiometer is at minimum (Which, I assume, is your intended 0V setting).  Note that the op-amp has no feedback -- it'll just go wherever its internal offsets and gain tell it to.  Since op-amps are *designed to work in closed-loop only*, no feedback means that the output can go wherever it wants to.

You're lucky it's only going to +1V (to give you -1V after the inverting stage).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fBz3wZ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I don't know what sources you're reading, or what circuits you've tried, but this circuit should work with just about any op-amp from the horribly obsolete LM741 to any current-production devices that can handle +/- 12V on their inputs.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fdhTBn.png)</sup>

Comment: This was exactly the circuit I built earlier. It didn't give me an output below 2V.

Comment: You used a TL084, with +/- 12V supplies, and nothing on the output?  If not, then no, it isn't _exactly_ the same circuit.  Welcome to op-amps, where the theory is easy and the practice is hard!

Answer (score 1):

Your power supply design is not acceptable. You need filter capacitors from both supplies to ground or the slightest unbalance in loading will cause large amounts of ripple voltage to ground. And you will have a lot of imbalance.

Fix that first.

Answer (score 1):

> I learnt that opamps in the unity gain, or buffer, configuration output a minimum of 2V no matter what the input is.

Not all op-amps. Just the particular op-amp type that you’re using. Every op-amp type has both an input voltage range, also called input common mode voltage range, and an output voltage range. The one you’re using has the limits you observe. If you used a rail-to-rail op-amp, it’d not have this limitation in general. If you used a different non rail-to-rail op app, it’d have a different voltage range limitation. It could also suffer from phase inversion where the op amp output goes “upside down”.

And then of course op-amps aren’t ideal “infinitely strong” voltage sources. Their outputs have limits in how much current they can source. And they also have limits in how much capacitive paid they can take before they become unstable. Those are practical considerations in power supply design that involves op-amps.